# How to count function template instantiations

Tags: c++, templates

Say I have a function template `func` and it gets instantiated several times with the same template parameter. The individual instances with the same template parameter should be counted  (from 0 on) and the instance count should be accessible from `func`'s implementation. Clearly, a static member is not what I am searching for. Instead, it looks to me that instance counting needs to be implemented with compile-time type computation.

Example (user code):

```
{
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    func<float>();           // This should be instance number 0
  }
  func<float>();             // This should be instance number 1
}
```

Despite the runtime loop the first instance of `func` gets the number 0. That is over all loop iterations the instance number should not change. Only when the loop exits and the function is called again, the number should be incremented, namely to 1.

Original template:

```
template<class T> void func() {}
```

Possible ways to access the instance count:

```
template<class T,int COUNT> void func() {}   // instance number as template parameter
template<class T> void func(int count) {}    // or as function argument
```

Can this be done with some fancy call wrapper? If so, how?

I fear it's not possible... But, right now I have a good use for it ..

Comment: What is the problem you are solving where this is your solution?

Comment: I think I can't explain it in the small comment field, but I'll try. At the end I want to reuse communication objects (to an accelerator) which are already created by previous calls to the function. The real implementation of `func` takes pointers as arguments. These pointers must be copied to the accelerator. However, if I have a chance to know that the same pointers were used I can reuse the pointers already copied. I seek a compile time solution to avoid a runtime check.

Comment: There is a trick that may be done using macros, but it will work only inside a single compilation unit. Does it fit you?

Comment: No, multiple source files.

Comment: @Frank: Don't avoid the runtime check. Really. Computer time (like checking a pointer) is really, really, really cheap.

Comment: @Frank: This sounds like premature optimization, which is generally a bad idea. (Just adding to thiton's advice.)

Comment: So, then it's technically not possible to do with template meta-programming.

Comment: @Frank, definitely most likely not possible ;) (You can't exclude for definite the possibility that some mp guru will stumble into this and decide to show how it's done..) For us mere mortals, stick to the obivous way...

Comment: Why does the fact that the function is called on a single line imply that it does the same thing each time?

Comment: Can you show us the runtime solution that you want to avoid so we know what your goal is?

Comment: `func` in reality is the evaluate function of a expression template library. `T` represents a syntax tree. The functions collects all pointers to data objects in the expression and puts them into a container which gets copied. This copy takes long. Now, if all pointer values are the same (in the same order) compared to a prior run and `T` is the same then I can assume that the same operation is carried out again on the same input data. Now I can use some smart object to reuse the pointers -- and save the time for the copy.

Answer (score 3):

An instantiated function template is a function. Each function only exists once in your program. Therefore, you cannot count instantiations, because there is only a single instantiation of `func<float>`.

Comment: Agreed there is only 1 instance of `func<float>` but therefore I said you can add another integral template parameter `func<int,float>`. That is a different function template instance.

Comment: Except this is a populated function template. Your point still stands - the compiler has emitted one and only one implementation of `func` in this example code.

Comment: Yes, but can't `func` be a wrapper that instantiates `func_impl<count,float>()` and forward the arguments (if there are any)?

Comment: @Frank, nope, the template parameter has to be a compile time constant, there is no way to increment a compile time constant (unless you use something like `__COUNTER__` but that is per translation unit)

Comment: Again agreed, compile time numbers are constant but you can instantiate a new one out of it adding to it 1, can't you?

Comment: @Frank, how? sketch the function out as you see it working, and you will realise immediately that the "adding 1 to it" is a run-time operation...

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class T> class impl {
    template<int count>
    static void funcImpl() {}
}

#define func funcImpl<__COUNTER__>

...

impl<float>::func()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is not an option (see main comments).

Comment: `T` is a type representing an expression (ET).

Answer (score 0):

What you explain in your comment is that you want to cache the function results. This is called [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). You should perhaps create a full class to handle the function's memoization for each template argument.

If you expect the function to reduce to the same value each time, perhaps check first if the compiler does that by itself (`g++ -S -g` shouldn't be too unreadable...).